# upload file from C# and get in PHP

Tags: c#, php, download, upload

I want to know when I upload file in C# with this code:

Please check code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2996904/7423018)

Usage:

```
NameValueCollection nvc = new NameValueCollection();
nvc.Add("id", "TTR");
nvc.Add("btn-submit-photo", "Upload");
HttpUploadFile("http://your.server.com/upload", @"C:\test\test.jpg", "file", "image/jpeg",
    nvc);
```

After that how can I get file in PHP?

I know I can get `value` from  `POST` and `GET`, but how to get `File` and save that in server?

I know how to save file in server but I can't find any parameters in `POST` or `GET` for get file.

`GET` parameters: `$_GET['link'];` or for `POST`: `$_POST['link'];`

What parameters for `FILE`?

Comment: These are known as super globals. See http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php

Comment: `$_FILES` for files, don't you think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
print_r($_FILES);
```

and example how upload: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp

Change only "fileToUpload" to correct from $_FILES

Comment: Multiple files upload https://github.com/fxstar/PhpJsCss/blob/master/multiupload.php